# I use viewmodel to bass to list of objects one to use in partialview of strongly type but this error is occurred

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcApplication1.Models.News]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.News'.

```
   //my Controller
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     CouncilDb _db=new CouncilDb() ;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var News = _db.News
                 .Take(10);


        var Banner = (from r in _db.Banner orderby r.id descending select r).FirstOrDefault();


        maz  model = new maz();
        model.Banner = Banner;
        model.News = News.ToList();

        return View(model);

    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_db != null)
        {
            _db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

    public class maz
    {
        public List<News>   News { get; set; }

        public Banner Banner { get; set; }
    }
```

//Index view

```
@model MvcApplication1.Controllers.maz 

@{ 
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<!-- Banner -->


 <!-- Banner -->
        <div id="banner">
            <h2> @Model.Banner.H2</h2>
            <span class="byline">  @Model.Banner.Span  </span>
        </div>


@Html.Partial("_News",Model.News    )
```

//Partialview

```
 @model MvcApplication1.Models.News

<!-- Carousel -->
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="reel">

        <article>
            <a class="image featured">
                <img src="@Model.ImgUrl  " alt="" /></a>
            <header>
                <h3>@Html.ActionLink(@Model.Title , "serch", "Home")</h3>
            </header>
            <p>@Model.Body </p>
        </article>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.News` property of your model is of type `List<News>` not `News` so the model declaration in your partial view and the model you are passing to it don't match.

Depending on what you want to acheive, you can either loop through the List inside the index view:

```
@foreach (var news in Model.News)
{
    @Html.Partial("_News", news)
}
```

or adjust the partial view model declaration and loop there

```
@model List<News>
....
@for (var news in Model)
{
<article>
    <a class="image featured">
        <img src="@news.ImgUrl" alt="" /></a>
    <header>
        <h3>@Html.ActionLink(@news.Title , "serch", "Home")</h3>
    </header>
    <p>@news.Body</p>
</article>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straightforward, once you get past the generic syntax. In C#-speak it's saying this:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'List<News>',
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'News'.
```

Your partial view is declared with a `@model` clause that specifies an item of type `News`:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.News
```

but when you pass in data to that partial view, what you're passing in is a `List<News>`:

```
@Html.Partial("_News",Model.News)
```

What you probably want is a loop (a `@foreach` or similar) that creates one partial view for each element in your `News` list.